# how to move class.bind condition from view to model in Aurelia repeat.for

Tags: javascript, aurelia

While implementing a class.bind I stumbled across one issue(at least I see it as an issue), I do not really like to have too much logic in the view and was thinking to move to the model of the component but it appeared to be tricky. I am implementing the step progress bar

```
<template >
  <ul class="all-steps">
    <li repeat.for="step of steps" class.bind="current === step ? 'active': (previous.indexOf(step) >= 0 ? 'done':'')">${$index + 1}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Is there any way I can move all this class assigning logic to a view? I tried to create a binding function with dirty binding but apparently passing the `step` from the view causes `Unhanded rejection exception` any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is write a function that takes the various parameters. The best part is that this won't trigger dirty checking. Aurelia will only call the function if the value of the parameters change.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=837b35139b924682143e74f4e7ca85ba**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <ul class="all-steps">
    <li repeat.for="step of steps" class="${calculateClass(current, step)}">Step 1: ${$index + 1} (${calculateClass(current, step)})</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  current = 3;
  steps = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
  previous = [ 1, 2 ];

  calculateClass(current, step) {
    console.log(`called. current = ${current}, step = ${step}`)
    if(current === step) {
      return 'active';
    } else if (this.previous.indexOf(step) >= 0 ) {
      return 'done';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
      li {
        background-color: green;
      }

      li.active {
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      li.done {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>

    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/aurelia.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/babel.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['aurelia-bootstrapper']);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great thanks the only thing I was missing was when the function is triggered :)